# Where do I find the language icon change mention that happened in macOS 12.4 upgrade?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, language

I cannot find the mention about the removal of flags and replacing them with country codes for language switcher.

I am talking about this change:

[image]

Previously there was a full-fledged American flag icon instead of "US".

Can anybody help to locate that in some official release docs?

Comment: May be because some people complained about flags like in [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253384595) : a guy wanted to have Russian keyboard but not the Russia flag.

Comment: This is close to being off topic since there's not a practical question I can see and it's more about what Apple has or hasn't done in the form of a yes/no question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get back the input source flags on my menu bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441267/how-do-i-get-back-the-input-source-flags-on-my-menu-bar)

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen it mentioned yet in any Apple release docs, but this general topic has already been discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441267/how-do-i-get-back-the-input-source-flags-on-my-menu-bar).

Comment: I would very much expect Apple to not explain this as flags are quite polarizing for reasons of international conflict. Language is the thing that's being switched and in many countries, the political borders do not reflect a unified language which changes far slower than redrawing a border. +1 for this answer, it's likely correct for the long haul and is correct now.